# $\ell_p$ is not closed in $\ell_ \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> prove $\ell_p$ is not closed in $\ell _\infty $ for any $1 \le p < \infty$.

A sequence of real numbers if just a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. So, we have a sequence of *functions* $f_n:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ and $f_n \in \ell _p $ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. They converge to some function $g$ in the sense that $\|f_n-g\|_p\to 0$. The goal is to prove that the function $g \in \ell _\infty ,g \notin \ell _p $.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as written, Pick any function $h \in \ell_p$, and define $f_i = h$ for all $i$. Then $g = h$ is in $\ell_p$.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $n^{-(1 + \varepsilon)}$ is summable for all $\varepsilon > 0$, but $n^{-1}$ is not summable.

Comment: You're considering closed sets of $\ell_\infty$ so convergence should be in *that* norm. As all functions/sequences in $\ell_p$ are bounded, we can see those functions as a subspace of $\ell_\infty$ too, not just as a space with its own norm.

Comment: You only need *one* point in the closure that is not in the set to refute closedness. This general thing you're trying to show is uncessary (and false to boot).

Comment: $a=(1,1/2^{\frac{1}{p}},...,1/n^{\frac{1}{p}},..)$ take sequence $a_n$ is the first n components of $a$. Does this sequence help?

Comment: @N.Quy .yes.this is true .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you have to find for each $1 \le p < \infty$ a *concrete* sequence $f_n$ in $\ell^p (\,\subseteq \ell_\infty)$ (so you have to show that they indeed are in that set, so they're $p$-summable) and $f \in \ell^\infty$ such that $f \notin \ell_p$ (show this!) and such that $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be what the question (as written) asks. I suspect, however, that it's what the question *should* be asking.